# Installation of django-classy-tags: ValueConstraintError

Tags: python, django, django-templates

When I try to install django-classy-tags I get an error that I do not understand.

Can somebody help me?

Unfortunately I could not find anything about this error.
See for the installation: https://github.com/divio/django-classy-tags/blob/master/docs/installation.rst
or: https://django-classy-tags.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

I use:

- python 2.7
- Django 1.10.4

I tried to install using:

- sudo pip install django-classy-tags

error message from pip:

```
Downloading/unpacking django-classy-tags
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django-classy-tags/
  URLs to search for versions for django-classy-tags:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/django-classy-tags/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/cf/59cc87cffc27cb374f245f15038463b8d5991e537872c089c0bf2458d288/django-classy-tags-0.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=c2d5ad6131dd89a9cdd931561ed0c3002ceb75ae7527fcc33e6b19f8dd090dde (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.1.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/d7/a4eba2805a21cf55219ccc8cd443f89e43ab5e508dd3056aaf579e70d87a/django-classy-tags-0.1.1.tar.gz#sha256=0286b3b7844c40f7ba35e787467572063f682d581cfa80c893da1a79394d7909 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.1.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/a8/c00ad565539fb18521566f1b4a63b21dfd30c86d3fc3349f9baaec0afe89/django-classy-tags-0.1.2.tar.gz#sha256=9927576d40cca9367b92c5253a82368cc71aea959f8668d3ca673e921e6e2865 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.1.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/85/dc5c70c2e21568847beb75086c1b3e3e5739aca5d25a129f07c0eebca393/django-classy-tags-0.1.3.tar.gz#sha256=2dc8f8a0592241dcb343f22cd249a01ef6fbb40a411e71e1d3f6a10303565231 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.1.3
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/a8/5d1117785586a2e59aa202ddc7e5069c7b7b88bc6a5ac0659e981b12e9b3/django-classy-tags-0.2.0.tar.gz#sha256=d868a862dd6a5f4dd232fbb6598c9bdef832a8d34bfe8bff2ad39e1ed8680af2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.2.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/ba/84d71fa5ee2503ef0dfb5ae3c96f8e3efb35ac5fdc99c21d085a420f926e/django-classy-tags-0.2.1.tar.gz#sha256=b01df591fca1fdf44eb968b97e8f664df77687abe90e7842bb1d1e2c748dabf3 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.2.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/6b/d2522547b22da30f4fe70b8f71500678dacc6ce603d8849f33afe37855be/django-classy-tags-0.2.2.tar.gz#sha256=182b480d14a296528af2bdd98bf490025356ccfe14efba2af80c969cb3e10887 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.2.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/fb/60026df54b571f3ca9410e733346e10a2fa7fd416fa7694415e6844d9124/django-classy-tags-0.3.0.tar.gz#sha256=52502dceaaa4aca79729644128af8b61d5e1ff1ad1671389e19a6da660022524 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.3.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/08/0f3bd91a6844f8112624396a2a9045b20d0ea9099dfc311d5d4dec18cd43/django-classy-tags-0.3.1.tar.gz#sha256=5d6b06a6f88afd839d5f251465a3fcfe9dde050eece30817ef6968643ba48967 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.3.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/22/f46057e5c66951b6f682e83f6456d1da30bdf208fc6c8bf98354d24a3fa9/django-classy-tags-0.3.2.tar.gz#sha256=6ba8f49b9d43e70dd6d994f2af0a4f040072cbb562252a3606c3e71eed4bd6a1 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.3.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/f1/b2e5d7d207d0b21e356f79ee075014a9854641009dd96afb71b30c0efb4f/django-classy-tags-0.3.3.tar.gz#sha256=4e343170448088a2f2b57c72c5884b864efef8a093500765287692fb77d2d511 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.3.3
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/b1/ed6e08020cd198d932cd9c72c987dbd82a493b3174f4e1a1abb095e597b7/django-classy-tags-0.3.3.1.tar.gz#sha256=69b6eb704e6ab9711a923e93039b7b658f9a086b990162bb78379342be763d70 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.3.3.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/f7/248d6b9b2beb5293a58fb8f07c47cd9b6c5591d79f00d2aecb8e4470c181/django-classy-tags-0.3.4.tar.gz#sha256=4f2b635ebe7b941290561f6d4a111eac5570b56ec57e30cdb1aa606a916a3c9f (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.3.4
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/d1/10928c2cc60e0c22cde3e613228a9a2f694cdd9a51edaad3a2e2aad3ae21/django-classy-tags-0.3.4.1.tar.gz#sha256=5ca2e8df0079f09c509ca280c2a9a453015c2911ecba26e332753fa8700c0bec (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.3.4.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/ef/0c60fe4f5e7d511a5e7ac3111958a93719bf74b4c15ee1d1346b92ff9e75/django-classy-tags-0.3.5.tar.gz#sha256=36ffea990d8e0442d0cb396468ad6519b051471fb8270bbca9156eaf7d8a1db2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.3.5
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4a/c4/cfa8c1347a12f9cd3698b4783a35ff21e5e53c303f4295ef55b39220f97b/django-classy-tags-0.4.tar.gz#sha256=6df0211e8c64d94673739bc880d0299c5c7d6c7659a62bcc406894891154a965 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.4
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/ee/c95b0d7fbb65b470ed3cce9d2de8af97e306c3b7874f3ff79678e47b0641/django-classy-tags-0.5.tar.gz#sha256=13927798e44659db8a1fcd0e402f1921d778f728ffabb9129367fec6abe721b6 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.5
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/6b/fe605042d1343dd058c1c75a088544673e49fdfeca18565dcae16a0b215d/django-classy-tags-0.5.1.tar.gz#sha256=d23eb74afc51e1eb393703838459c0424ba64dd203fc4cca26f7f1715717860f (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.5.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/ae/a35b5b54af9f36fcbbd60bd24505ced927a751773eeea9b2558e85c81e31/django-classy-tags-0.5.2.tar.gz#sha256=489e29a303be3288a7a0cab4a5b3fcafa1a34472143c1a26d966736b607bf0d3 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.5.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/67/20cba06e06174c2da9723750edb34adec3ca0a2cb3ab5a3753928fc72380/django_classy_tags-0.5.2-py2-none-any.whl#sha256=8161e0490f7f86e83bffb248f820c75eb4b21e9b053e7d0172221cdee665aefe (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.5.2
    Skipping https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/93/61a59603a18f3cd58b6a68dfbea7e6a49cff4c7f89671fa5014cd33c0219/django_classy_tags-0.5.2-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=ab42cd763ce79506e81f55a30fe88f950bddc17c2d2608c88c5cc18ad097aa6b (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/05/4dd245d581dd90ba0c9998c5c707a41b0ee4048277b83ee4ee02695f8a2e/django-classy-tags-0.6.1.tar.gz#sha256=00b785ce56ce0faf904c6a52acc03c5d623e6c8d90f831a6540accdf64bdbb73 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.6.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/b7/3705d4fc5699d2f3ccb79e65b0d5c8413607e58e73595e80a78eb8e33206/django_classy_tags-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=e57ff4e89649cd395bfe71e9c423f2c5360f2b631c5c72da3b6645b2a2d62013 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.6.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/10/a236760090219e56ca23dd9787afdec114d1b0664f43231a3e3f78a0deb5/django-classy-tags-0.6.2.tar.gz#sha256=9b8d6056b2aadc2e9e4f28df8c41f2c9546a3ef63785eadc33231d4487cc6212 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.6.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/16/03d6f6ebd74add77f8c2ae0fab799ae73a287ffaded9fcb6bd56fd339de4/django_classy_tags-0.6.2-py2-none-any.whl#sha256=fcd693880a1861ab53c8c75aa4f12066e175292e9ec39ec92168cc7ec04b9b5e (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.6.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/09/3c04c32676dcb00dd2937f0ec70b563991508ba79d1cdcf4a1bab298f52b/django-classy-tags-0.7.0.tar.gz#sha256=e55b09d8cea6995a768e5f05031fac5b1bd26cc52f232dc1c8a6be1b0a6653ba (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.7.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/2f/86b126d2546f6aab35f409a34fbba051a33b245daba00bed121982990ebf/django_classy_tags-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=d8ea7d1414b0734c549e6b52f088014f5980ca7f5ecf87c3997d1372d6f9c198 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.7.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/06/d71157fa0d2541c12da79fc10cd127a582cc85f015ad9ff36f3ba0017e42/django-classy-tags-0.7.1.tar.gz#sha256=ebffaeb1ade7fa354fb4feda4c11255335107bb0862dce0893b12a95262c5d81 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.7.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/fe/a4af1c86da5eb731aaeb9dcf8a52dad8af69ff509d930130382cc868ad0d/django_classy_tags-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=aeb544f720402583280573312b8c11588ef85cd15c769705aad85c47f8e3045e (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.7.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/0f/9eaa1cc7a6d994f299e613fe0937aca3b4a8fd319625186e57e3704c3ff7/django-classy-tags-0.7.2.tar.gz#sha256=068506291979ca973f74eb5744359fb319d4aa891cd0081c59da09b0e50ea094 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.7.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/8a/b88ec64b42236e4618861a62a334346daf1e9174cd406b50fd1073bad97e/django_classy_tags-0.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=9b21579ef0fcc2258e5397ff9134150e58d0482aef0c28b7e7369cbf35074a8c (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.7.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/64/a4a72d2bd04848864e7c39b30a3f44be05c328a7f7a4b6406369ad21daac/django-classy-tags-0.8.0.tar.gz#sha256=792f9161d0e22d55b4fab6fc297bab8ab072ffaa3075b227613a6d8473624db8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.8.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/7d/3d13d3303bd6118a910c72709d6892ffabe7e2df5e3353f722409348a032/django_classy_tags-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=f6d12f5a4df3e387795a0d9ef2836af389cae9a1fbebda035dac043d4722b1f7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/django-classy-tags/), version: 0.8.0
  Using version 0.8.0 (newest of versions: 0.8.0, 0.8.0, 0.7.2, 0.7.2, 0.7.1, 0.7.1, 0.7.0, 0.7.0, 0.6.2, 0.6.2, 0.6.1, 0.6.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3.5, 0.3.4.1, 0.3.4, 0.3.3.1, 0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.0, 0.1.3, 0.1.2, 0.1.1, 0.1.0)
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 825, in __call__
    stGetValueDecoder, self, substrateFun
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 391, in valueDecoder
    r.verifySizeSpec()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 252, in verifySizeSpec
    def verifySizeSpec(self): self._sizeSpec(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/type/constraint.py", line 32, in __call__
    '%s failed at: \"%s\"' % (self, sys.exc_info()[1])
ValueConstraintError: ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueSizeConstraint(1, 64)) failed at: "ValueSizeConstraint(1, 64) failed at: "SubjectAltName().setComponents(GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType( ... ))))""
```

I tried it with the current as well with older versions - same result:

- 0.8.0, 0.7.2, 0.7.1, 0.7.0, 0.6.2

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same error and stumbles over my question:

It seems that I found out what the underlying error was: PIP was not up to date!

After installing updates the error did not occur any more.